# I would like to analyze a TXT file, but the data is a 1 column array, and it needs to be a in a multi-column array

Tags: text-processing, csv, array, text-formatting, data

Is there a way for me to manipulate the data (i.e.; change some feature of, so that it looks like it should, a multi-column array) without having to manually go through it? There are thousands of rows in it.

Here is an image of the first 10 lines.

I have added an image of another file that is having the same issue. Note my cursor is in column B, and all of the information is in column A. The first one I was able to work with because they had uploaded a re-processed file for us, but this one does not have that luxury. One commenter put forth several answers , and I am going to be looking into each of those.

[image]

[image: Added picture of what these files look like in a csv format]

Comment: Yes, there is. 1) Excel, since 2007, supports 2^20 ( 1,048,576 ) data rows. You could import the data into Excel for manipulation. The data I see from your screenshot looks like it is in tab-separated value (TSV) format, a variant of comma separated value format. Excel will accept a TSV.file & turn it into a spreadsheet. 2) Or, you can use text processing tools like grep, sed, and awk; see http://tecmint.com/linux-file-operations-commands . We don't know if the screenshot provided is representative, so please click [edit] & give us a representative sample as text added to your question.

Comment: That looks like multi column data already?

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 solutions (1st is powerful, 2nd is simple, 3rd is a quickie):

1. [apache drill](https://drill.apache.org/). It can [parse TSV](https://drill.apache.org/docs/text-files-csv-tsv-psv/) among many other formats. Though if it's a rare occasion you deal with problem like this it could be too heavyweight.
2. use a python or perl oneliner to just split the row and reprocess it, for example:

```
$ ps ax | head
   PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
     1 ?        Ss     2:40 /sbin/init
     2 ?        S      0:08 [kthreadd]
     3 ?        S      0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
     5 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
     8 ?        S     13:32 [rcu_sched]
     9 ?        S      0:00 [rcu_bh]
    10 ?        S      0:07 [migration/0]
    11 ?        S<     0:00 [lru-add-drain]
    12 ?        S      0:18 [watchdog/0]
$ ps ax | head |perl -n -e 'sub mynormalize($){ $r = shift;$r->[4]=substr($r->[4], 0, 2); return $r}; my @row = split; print(join("\t", @{ normalize(\@row) }), "\n"); '
PID     TTY     STAT    TIME    CO
1       ?       Ss      2:40    /s
2       ?       S       0:08    [k
3       ?       S       0:00    [k
5       ?       S<      0:00    [k
8       ?       S       13:32   [r
9       ?       S       0:00    [r
10      ?       S       0:07    [m
11      ?       S<      0:00    [l
12      ?       S       0:18    [w
```

3. use vim+regex or sed. Same as in #2 but for simpler transformations.